# Detection mouse click on facebook like button (from chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, facebook-like

I am developing a chrome extension which will show an alert when user clicks on facebook like button.

I'm using jQuery for this purpose but it's not working.

Here is the code

```
$("button").click(function(){
alert("Like");
});
```

I also tried this code, as the like button is inside an iframe but still no luck!

```
var abc = $(document).find('iframe:first').contents().find('html:first').find('body:first');
abc.find("button").click(function(){
alert("Like");
});
```

manifest.json (I added permissions to this file)

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "http://*.facebook.com/", "https://*.facebook.com/"
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first problem might be the fact that in most cases, the 'like' is an `<a>` not a button, so `$('button')` would not select it. As for detecting the `like` link being clicked this is all that is needed:

**manifest.json**

```
 "permissions": [
   "tabs","*://*.facebook.com/*"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [{
   "matches": ["*://*.facebook.com/*"],
   "js": ["jquery.js","click.js"]
 }]
```

**click.js**

```
// For most of the likes on things such as comments and pictures and all that
$('a.UFILikeLink').click(function(){
  console.log('Like link was clicked somewhere');
});
// For the Like 'Button' that can be found on pages 
$('input[value="Like"]').click(function(){
  console.log('Like button was clicked somewhere');
});
```

Comment: I copied the same code that u posted above and also included the jquery.js, but when i click on "like button" nothing happens. There is no log. I also replaced console.log with alert() but still nothing happens.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed That one is an `<input>` with a value of `Like` I have updated my answer to include those as well.